# Matrix logical operation with different number of channels in OpenCV

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I have a problem with matrix logical operation. I want to use `bitwise_and` with image A and image B to get the result image C.

The image data type are all `Mat`, image A was processed after some functions and it was a binary image with 3 channels. Image B was also a binary image after some processing but just with 1 channel.

Because the channel numbers are different, I get error when do `bitwise_and`.

How should I do to merge the channel or any else methods to solve this problem?

Here shows image A,B,C:

[image: image A + image B = image C]

Comment: use `cvtColor` with `COLOR_GRAY2BGR`, or `COLOR_BGR2GRAY` to make images A and B the same number of channels, then you can "AND" them. You can also use `Mat C = A & B;`. You want C to be 1 or 3 channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `A` and `B` to have same size, type and number of channels. You can use `cvtColor` to convert from 3 to 1 channel, or viceversa. It depends on the type you want for `C`:

```
Mat A; // CV_8UC3
Mat B; // CV_8UC1
```

If you want `C` to be 3 channels:

```
cvtColor(B, B, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
Mat C;
bitwise_and(A,B,C); // C will be 3 channel, CV_8UC3
```

else if you want `C` to be 1 channel:

```
cvtColor(A, A, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
Mat C;
bitwise_and(A,B,C); // C will be 1 channel, CV_8UC1
```

Also, if you don't need to use a mask, you can simply do:

```
Mat C = A & B;
```

Answer (score 1):

I do like the following in **Java**.

Thresholded channel 1.
webcam_image channel 3.

**OPENCV 3.0**

```
// convert 3  channel
Imgproc.cvtColor(thresholded, thresholded, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
Core.bitwise_and(thresholded, webcam_image, webcam_image);
```

Maybe it'll help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the three channel matrix and apply bitwise "and operation" separately on each channel:

```
vector<Mat> channels(3);
// split img:
split(imageA, channels);

bitwise_and(channels[0], imageB, channels[0]);
bitwise_and(channels[1], imageB, channels[1]);
bitwise_and(channels[2], imageB, channels[2]);
```

Then merge channels to get 3 channel Mat object:

```
 merge(channels, imageC);
```